# API_ID error on x64 Telegram TDLIB (not x86)

Tags: json, 64-bit, telegram, tdlib

I have a strange behaviour when working with the Telegram TDLIB. I've compiled TDLib for C++ Windows Library and have now the tdjson.dll for Win32 and Win64.
My app is using the WIN32 version without any problem, but when I try to set TdLib parameters on the Win64 via setTdlibParameters and JSON I get the following error:

```
{"@type":"error","code":400,"message":"Valid api_id must be provided. Can be obtained at https://my.telegram.org"}
```

I even use the same JSON string as used in the WIN32 version:

```
{"@type":"setTdlibParameters","parameters":{"database_directory":"C:\\tdlib","use_file_database":true,"use_chat_info_database":true,"use_message_database":true,"use_secret_chats":true,"api_id":123456789,"api_hash":"5485ed51254e12547ae5555555e555d0","system_language_code":"en","device_model":"Desktop","application_version":"0.1","enable_storage_optimizer":true}}
```

However, I always got the invalid API_ID error with WIN64. Why is the same JSON request not working with x64 DLL version?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered here: https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/2211

Starting from TDLib v1.8.6+ setTdlibParameters values must be inlined and i can see in your JSON examples you haven't inlined the parameters.

To inline setTdlibParameters values remove the key/array parameters. So your JSON will be like:

```
{
"@type":"setTdlibParameters",
"use_test_dc":false,
"database_directory":"",
"files_directory":"",
"database_encryption_key":"",
"use_file_database":false,
"use_chat_info_database":false,
"use_message_database":false,
"use_secret_chats":false,
"api_id":1245678,
"api_hash":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"system_language_code":"en",
"device_model":"Desktop",
"system_version":"",
"application_version":"0.1",
"enable_storage_optimizer":false,
"ignore_file_names":false
}
```

This should work fine in TDLib 1.8.6+.